# Run gcov tool using c++ compiler

Tags: c++, code-coverage, automake, gcov

I am working, for the first time, with the coverage tool gcov to analyze a large project.
I have a directories structure like this:

```
    HW
     -FooHW1.cpp
     -FooHW1.h
     -FooHW2.cpp
     -FooHW2.h
     -...
     -Makefile.am
    Lib1
     -FooLib1.cpp
     -FooLib1.h
     -FooLib2.cpp
     -FooLib2.h
     -...
     -Makefile.am

    Lib2
     ...
     -Makefile.am
    Lib3
     ...
     -Makefile.am
    Main
     -main.cpp
     -main.h
     -Makefile.am
```

Each directory has its own Makefile generated using automake to generates dependecies and whatsoever where the compiler used is c++.

Since my objective is the analyses of the statement coverage I tried to use gcov adding the following lines to each Makefile.am to generate my .gcno and .gcda files in order to use gcov:

```
    AM_CXXFLAGS = -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
    AM_LDFLAGS = -fprofile-arcs
```

Unfortunately even if it compiles it doesn't create (or link) the several *.o and when invoking gcov it usually gives me the error:

```
    undefined __gcov_init
```

I also tried susbtituing, according to *http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-coverage-536*,  the upper instructions to:

```
    AM_CXXFLAGS = --coverage
    AM_LDFLAGS = --coverage
```

but it doesn't do the trick for me.

I would like to specify that this is the first experience with the gcov tool and in dealing with large c++ projects.
Thaks for your help.

Comment: I'd guess you forgot to link your code with lcov.

Comment: Isn't lcov just a graphical front-head for the gcov tool? I'm really inexperienced so i don't get your suggestion, could you be more clear? thanks!

Comment: Yes, I may have been confusing this. `AM_LDFLAGS = --coverage` should do what I meant.

Comment: I added the following in the Makefile.am:
`AM_CXXFLAGS = --coverage`
`AM_LDFLAGS = --coverage`
`AM_CFLAGS = -shared`
and it finally creates the *gcno files, i couldn't actually test the overall cause i had some other problems, hope it'll work.
Thanks!

Comment: You can investigate by `make VERBOSE=1`, and review the linkage flags

Answer (score 0):

http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/code-coverage-with-gcov and
http://www.slideshare.net/maguschen/using-gcov-and-lcov are good sources for using gcov/lcov (with this help I've managed to use lcov in really big, complicated project)

lcov gives you possibility to show results of coverage in html format (nice percentages for listed files or even for lines in source files).

Oh, and I hope you do realize it's a dynamical coverage, so you have to actually run the program to get any coverage (building should only create `.gcno` files).

Comment: thanks, I know i have to run it in order to get my coverage(that's actually the objective of my project in order to test some module of a mobile robot)! took a look on the lcov output and it's actually much nicer and comprehensible than the gcov one so i'll try to use it once i'll be able to make it work, the only difference should be when invoking it, am i right? 
`lcov ` instead of `gcov`
Thanks!

Comment: The first link http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/code-coverage-with-gcov is 404 now.

Comment: Latest archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20171013210930/bobah.net/d4d/tools/code-coverage-with-gcov

Answer (score -1):

link the library gocv

```
-lgcov
```

that should help